# Почему размер ArrayList-а равна нулю?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть **list** , в которую хочу добавить данные которые беру из базы. Есть функция **func** , где я добавляю в мой **list** записи. Казалось бы после вызванной функции  , размер **list**-а должен увеличиться . Чтобы удостовериться в этом я проверил размер сразу же после вызова функции **func**. Но размер оказался равен нулю. Но если проверить размер **list**-а внутри функции **func** , то он вовсе не ноль. В чем может быть причина? Мне кажется я не знаю какую-то простую базовую вещь.

P.S : Для читабельности я минимизировал размер кода

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<Task> list ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);

    list = new ArrayList<>() ;
    func() ; // вызов функции

    tx.setText("Size:" + list.size()); //проверка размера
}
public void func()
{
  Backendless.Persistence.of(Task.class).find(new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Task>>() {
       @Override
       public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Task> response) {
        Iterator<Task> it = response.getCurrentPage().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
           {
               Task t =  it.next() ;
               list.add(t) ;
        }
           //tx.setText("Size:" + list.size()); // проверка размера внутри функции



       }

       @Override
       public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "WRONG!!!" ,         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



       }
   }) ;


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаток Java, но, судя по документации, вы используете [асинхронную версию](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_basic_search.htm) поиска. Это значит, как минимум, две вещи:

1. Поток выполнения программы (после вызова `find`) не будет прерван.
2. На выполнение `find` потребуется какое-то время.

Из этого следует, что вы вызываете метод `func()`, он запускает асинхронную операцию и тут же возвращается обратно в метод `onCreate` где вы проверяете размер коллекции. Но, метод `find` ещё не успел завершить работу и вызвать [callback](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) `handleResponse`, где вы, по вашей задумке, заполняете коллекцию `list`.

Тут несколько путей решения вашей проблемы:

1. Переместить/вызвать код проверки в подходящий метод `AsyncCallback`
2. Использовать синхронную версию `find` (т.е. ту, которая блокирует поток выполнения программы пока выполняется)

Всё та же [документация](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_basic_search.htm) подсказывает подходящий метод:

```
public BackendlessCollection<Map> Backendless.Persistence.of( "TABLE-NAME" ).find()
```

Comment: Можете уточнить про  'Дождаться выполнения асинхронной операции' ? Как этого достичь?

Comment: Немного скорректировал ответ. Возможно, ещё способы подскажут знатоки Java.